# Why doesn't returning a reference to the current object always return the same reference?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I am relatively new to Java and I am trying to make a class called `VisualObject` whose instances can be dragged and dropped between `JPanel`s.

This is the `getTransferData` function for `VisualObject`, which implements `Transferable`:

```
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor d)
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {

        if (d != visualObjectDataFlavor) {
            throw  new UnsupportedFlavorException(d);
        }   
        return this;
   }
```

However, in the `TransferHandler` for my `JPanel`s I run this line

```
System.out.println(t.getTransferData(VisualObject.visualObjectDataFlavor).equals(t.getTransferData(VisualObject.visualObjectDataFlavor)));
```

And it always returns `false`. How can I actually return a consistent pointer to the object that is being transferred? Or is there a better way to transfer it?

**Second Edit:**

My original code is still below, but the problem still occurs in this much simplified code:

```
package trytwo;

import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimplifiedVisualObject implements Transferable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SimplifiedVisualObject a, b;
        a = new SimplifiedVisualObject();
        b = new SimplifiedVisualObject();
        try {
            System.out.println(a.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor).equals(b.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)));
        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Edit:

Below are the three classes that I wrote: `VisualObject` (the `Transferable`), `ObjectFrame` (which holds the `VisualObject`s in its content pane), and `Main`, which just creates two `ObjectFrame`s.

`VisualObject`:

```
package tryone;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class VisualObject extends JComponent implements Transferable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7105793092357377791L;
    public static DataFlavor visualObjectDataFlavor = new DataFlavor(VisualObject.class, "Visual Object");

    public VisualObject() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setLayout(null);
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    public Transferable getTransferData(DataFlavor d)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {

        if (d != visualObjectDataFlavor) {
            throw  new UnsupportedFlavorException(d);
        }   
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        DataFlavor d[] = {visualObjectDataFlavor};
        return d;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor d) {
        if (d == visualObjectDataFlavor) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public VisualObject getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

`ObjectFrame`:

```
package tryone;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;


public class ObjectFrame extends JFrame implements DragGestureListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4330669242071962048L;
    protected Cursor draggingCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
    private JPanel panel;



    public ObjectFrame() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Object Tray");

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        final DragSource ds = new DragSource();
        final DragGestureListener handle = this;

        panel.setTransferHandler(new ObjectTransferHandler());

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                VisualObject v = null;


                v = new VisualObject();
                v.setSize(50, 50);
                v.setLocation(100, 100);
                ds.createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(v,
                        DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, handle);
                panel.add(v);

                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent dge) {
        if (dge.getComponent() instanceof Transferable) {
            dge.startDrag(draggingCursor, (Transferable) dge.getComponent());
        }
    }

    private class ObjectTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5072686271469629699L;

        public ObjectTransferHandler() {
        }

        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport t) {
            if (t.isDataFlavorSupported(VisualObject.visualObjectDataFlavor))  {
                return true;
            }
            return false;        
        }

        public boolean importData(TransferSupport ts) {
            Transferable t = ts.getTransferable();
            try {
                System.out.println(t.getTransferData(VisualObject.visualObjectDataFlavor) == (t.getTransferData(VisualObject.visualObjectDataFlavor)));

                return true;
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

`Main`:

```
package tryone;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f1 = new ObjectFrame();
        JFrame f2 = new ObjectFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` and `hashcode` method in `VisaualObject`? and why are you returning `Object` from that method instead of `Transferable`?

Comment: If you've implemented equals badly it could always return false, as an interesting test see if == also returns false ( == (sort of) looks at the memory address and tests if they're the same object)

Comment: @RohitJain, I have not implemented those methods. My understanding was that left unimplemented `equals` checks if the reference is literally the same. Perhaps I am wrong? No idea why that's returning `Object` instead of `Transferable`, that method was auto-generated by Eclipse. Should I change it to `Transferable`?

Comment: @RichardTingle == also returns false. The weird thing (at least the way I understand it) is that `this.equals(this)` returns `true` within `VisualObject`. I even tried making a method called `getThis`, which literally returns `this`, and then comparing two calls of `getThis` and found that they were equal! I don't know why `getThis` should always return the same value but `getTransferData` won't.

Comment: @user2490023 Your understanding regarding the non overridden equals() is correct. There'll be something interesting going on here. If you could post a completed (but simplified) version that demonstrates the problem (and preferably very little else) we'll have a look at it.

Comment: @user2490023 I.e. this: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @RichardTingle added the code which is self-contained, compilable, and hopefully short.

Comment: I suggest you write the simplest example of code which demonstrates your concern.  I find it hard to believe the problem only occurs when you have every line written as you have it.  For example, do you really need any GUI related code at all?  e.g. start with one class called A and another called B with one or two methods depending on how many you need.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thanks for the reality-check. After some experimenting I found a much simpler example that still has the problem and I added it to my question.

Comment: @sync Is it deliberate that in your dimplified version you use both a and b; System.out.println( **a** .getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor).equals( **b** .getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)));

Comment: @RichardTingle No, that was a really stupid mistake, sorry about that. I tried running the example with only "a" and it works as expected, i.e. `true` is printed. I am now experimenting with the goal of re-creating the error with less code.

Comment: @sync I'm not totally sure whats happening but you seem to be getting a `RuntimeException` when you return `this` (I have no idea how), its being hidden high up the chain (outside your code and silently dealt with). Change your `importData` method's catch to catch all `Exceptions` and you'll see it (in `ObjectFrame`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **SimplifiedVisualObject** version: The `getTransferData()` method return `this`. Since you are creating two different instances you are effectively comparing `a.equals(b)` which in general is always false unless `equals()` is overriden.

Regarding your **original question:** If you debug your code you will see that this is also the case with the `VisualObject`. Every time you call `getTransferData()` a different instance is returned thus the `equals()` comparison returns false.

If you use `DataFlavor.imageFlavor` it will work as expected though I cannot explain exactly why.

Perhaps when using an unknown flavor the default drag & drop implementation does not know how to handle it. As a result the transferable object is serialized and de-serialized during the transfer resulting in always creating a different instance.

**Edit:** Actually the answer is given by the [Java tutorial that suggests](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html) that when you know that you will only transfer objects locally (inside the same application) you should create your new `DataFlavor` like `visualObjectDataFlavor = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + ";class=tryone.VisualObject");` (to have it as a static field as in your example use a static initializer block). This will let the system know that you are transfering a local object in the application so it will return the same instance passing your object comparison test.

Comment: You're definitely right about **SimplifiedVisualObject**, that was a dumb mistake on my part. You're also right about DataFlavor.imageFlavor fixing the problem. It's a quick-fix for now, but I wonder why choosing a different flavor changes anything. Thanks for the help, you've definitely started to shed some light on where the problem is.

Comment: @sync The missing part was how to tell the DnD mechanism that you are transfering local objects so there is no need for serialization. See my updated answer